# WKWebView behavior. Reloading after Image picker returns

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, wkwebview

I am getting a weird behavior of a WKWebview. Resuming the problem is that after the web content ask for a image, the app opens automatically an image picker controller, and after select the image, the WKWebview starts reloading the whole page and I lost my current state, so the image selection does not works.

The wkwebview is contained in a custom navigation controller and that navigation controller is contained in a ViewController.

This is a little part of code:

```
if(isNewProfile)
    _webvc = [[DJTWebViewVC alloc] initWithOutDataObject:_dataUser];
else
    _webvc = [[DJTWebViewVC alloc] initWithDataObject:_dataObject];

CGFloat WEBNAVOFFSET = [self setWebNavOffset];

_webnav = [[DJTWebNavVC alloc] initWithRootViewController:_webvc];
[_webnav.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, c_width, c_height-WEBNAVOFFSET)];

[self.view addSubview:_webnav.view];
```

The image picker is called from webvc that it is the wkwebview host. Here you can see that webnav contains webvc, and self.view contains webnav. I suppose this is the problem. Is there any way to set the view which the image controller should be fired? Or there is anybody facing this issue and has a workaround?

Comment: Hi, please post here if you get the solution for this. I'm getting a similar issue on iPad

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm having the exact same problem now and there doesn't seem to be any solution on the internet. If I present the image picker webview modally, everything works. But when it's in a navigation controller, it reloads on picking the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the problem is the way the web view is being called, the solution I used to make it work was like this. First define a global var to know if the web view is previously loaded, so initialize it this way:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL isPreviouslyLoaded;
```

In the `viewDidLoad` function I added this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ...
    
    self.isPreviouslyLoaded = NO;
}
```

Then in the `viewDidAppear` function I used the full code of the question this way:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if(!self.isPreviouslyLoaded){
        [self loadWkWebNavigationController: YES];
        self.isPreviouslyLoaded = YES;
    }
}
```

Finally the code to load the web view:

```
- (void)loadWkWebNavigationController:(BOOL)isNewProfile
{
    if(isNewProfile)
        _webvc = [[DJTWebViewVC alloc] initWithOutDataObject:nil];
    else
        _webvc = [[DJTWebViewVC alloc] initWithDataObject:nil];
    
    CGFloat WEBNAVOFFSET = [self setWebNavOffset];
    
    _webnav = [[DJTWebNavVC alloc] initWithRootViewController:_webvc];
    [_webnav.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height+WEBNAVOFFSET, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height-self.navigationController.navigationBar.bounds.size.height-WEBNAVOFFSET)];
        
    [self.view addSubview:_webnav.view];
    
}
```

This is the way I do not reload the view if it is previously loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I was reloading the webview each time the NavigationView appeared.  So i added some code to prevent reloading if the hostname matched the one I want.